# Using the COUNT function in SQL

Tags: sql, select, count

First and Foremost, this is part of an assignment.

I am trying to use the COUNT function as part of a query in relation to the Northwind database. The query should return the CustomerID, CompanyName, and **the number of of orders placed for each respective customer**.

Of course the first two parts are easy, but I can't get the COUNT function to work properly. The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, COUNT(Customers.CustomerID)
FROM Orders, Customers
WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
```

What would be the correct syntax to use COUNT in that fashion? It would look like:

```
CompanyID | CompanyName | # of orders
    1     | Company A   | 4
    2     | Company B   | 3
    3     | Company C   | 5
```

All examples thus far have been using the COUNT function by itself, and not part of a more complex query.

Comment: You'll want to research `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hint: You have to use `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOIN` (so that customers with no order show up)

Comment: This is an assginment. Perhaps you can try some more before coming here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `group by` clause, which will allow you to split your result in to groups, and perform the aggregate function (`count`, in this case), per group:

```
SELECT   Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, COUNT(*)
FROM     Orders, Customers
WHERE    Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName
```

Note: Although this is not part of the question, it's recommended to use explicit `join`s instead of the deprecated implicit join syntax you're using. In this case, the query would look like:

```
SELECT   Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, COUNT(*)
FROM     Orders
JOIN     Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query should work.

```
    SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, COUNT(*)
    FROM Orders, Customers
    WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID group by Orders.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `group by` clause. Your query should look like this

```
select CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, count(CustomerID)
from Orders JOIN Customers using(CustomerID)
group by CustomerID;
```

Notice that I used the `Join` syntax which is more concise when joining tables.

Answer (score 0):

When using aggregate functions like COUNT(), all columns have to be part of  aggregate functions. The `GROUP BY` statement should solve your problem. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are learning SQL, you should learn proper explicit `join` syntax.   Simple rule:  never use a comma in the `from` clause.

Second, your query should use `group by` instead of `distinct`.  In fact, it is more important to learn `group by` than to learn `distinct`, because you can generally write `select distinct` using `group by`.

So, where you are heading is:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName, COUNT(c.CustomerID)
FROM Orders o JOIN
     Customers c
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName;
```

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use the `using` keyword or just a matter of preference, I'm curious ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard . . . `using` is not supported by all databases.